# How to send a "hello" to server and reply a "hi"?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcpserver

With my code I can read a message on the server and write from the client. But I am not being able to write a response from the server and read in the client.

The code on the `client`

```
var cli = new TcpClient();

cli.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6800);

string data = String.Empty;

using (var ns = cli.GetStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ns))
    {
        sw.Write("Hello");
        sw.Flush();

        //using (var sr = new StreamReader(ns))
        //{
        //    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //}
    }
}

cli.Close();
```

The code on the `server`

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
tcpListener.Start();

while (run)
{
    var client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

    string data = String.Empty;

    using (var ns = client.GetStream())
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ns))
        {
            data = sr.ReadToEnd();

            //using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ns))
            //{
            //    sw.WriteLine("Hi");
            //    sw.Flush();
            //}
        }
    }
    client.Close();
}
```

How can I make the server reply after reading the data and make the client read this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using

```
TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

, you can write back to the client directly without needing it to self-identify.  **The code you have will actually work** if you use `Stream.Read()` or `.ReadLine()` instead of `.ReadToEnd()`.  `ReadToEnd()` will block forever on a network stream, until the stream is closed.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412686/c-how-to-send-multiline-string-over-namedpipe/4413156#4413156) to a similar question, or from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx),

> ReadToEnd assumes that the stream
>   knows when it has reached an end. For
>   interactive protocols in which the
>   server sends data only when you ask
>   for it and does not close the
>   connection, ReadToEnd might block
>   indefinitely because it does not reach
>   an end, and should be avoided.

If you use ReadLine() at one side, you will need to use WriteLine() - not Write() - at the other side.  The alternative is to use a loop that calls Stream.Read() until there is nothing left to read.  You can see a full example of this for the server side in the [AcceptTcpClient() documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx).  The corresponding client example is in the [TcpClient documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Cheesy, inneficient, but does the trick on a one-time throwaway program:

- Client: In the stream, include the port and IP address it wishes to receive the response from.
- Client: Create a listener for that
  port and IP.
- Server: Read in the port/IP info and
  in turn connect, then send the reply
  stream.

However, [this is a great place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb332030.aspx), look into Sockets class for proper bi-directional communication.