# How can we send the data using TcpListener in c#?

Tags: c#

As per `MSDN`:

> The TcpListener class provides simple methods that listen for and accept incoming connection requests in blocking synchronous mode.

My team lead is asking to send the data using `TcpListener`. Is there any way or **feasible** to `receive` as well as `send` the data using `TCPListerner` ?

I already know how to receive the data using `TCPListener`, don't have any idea about sending the data with the same. I know `TCPClient` can be used to send the data but our team lead wants to do it using `TCPListerner`.

Please let me know your comments and let me know if it is feasible with some sample code.

Comment: Do you mean send reply to the server?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589605/how-to-send-a-hello-to-server-and-reply-a-hi see if this helps

Comment: Please see this line from my lead `` It would use TCPListner so that it is server in the case of sending data.`` so you might be right, its reply

Comment: `TcpListener` accepts connections - once the connection is established, the data can flow both ways. You just write data to the stream... It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Suppose I connected to a ``TCPListener`` using a ``TCPClient``, Now is there way send some data back to ``TCPClient`` using ``TCPListener`` ?

Comment: Yes. You write to the stream, and the client reads from the stream - it's as simple as that.

Comment: There is no direct method on TCPListener to write data to stream, but you can do this as a workaround: TcpClient client = TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); then you can send the stream back to the server.

Comment: @JonSkeet : yes I wrote some data to stream and tried to read from that stream on client side and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really.  The purpose of TcpListener is to *accept* a *new* connection.

However, the stream object you get from your TcpListener (once the connection is established) can be used for reading and writing.

Look here for more details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class MyTcpListener
{
  public static void Main()
  { 
    TcpListener server=null;   
    try
    {
      // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
      Int32 port = 13000;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // Buffer for reading data
      Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
      String data = null;

      // Enter the listening loop.
      while(true) 
      {
        Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        data = null;

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
        {   
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
       // Stop listening for new clients.
       server.Stop();
    }


    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
  }   
}
```